# Google App Engine - Search API index growth

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

I would like to know how can I estimate the growth (how much the size increasez in a period of time) of an index of App engine Search API (FTS) based on the number of entities inserted and amount of information. For this I would like to know basically how is the index size calculated (on what does it depend). Specifically:

1. When inserting new entities, is the growth (size) influenced by the  number of previous existing entities? (ie. is the growth exponential)? For ex. if I have 1000 entities and I insert 10, the index will grow with X bytes. But if I have 100000 entities and insert 10, will it increase with X or much more than X (exponentially, let' say 10*X) ?
2. Does the number of fields (properties) influences the size exponentially? For ex. if I have entity A with 2 fields and entity B with 4 fields (let's say identical in values, for mathematical simplicity) will the size increase, when adding entity B, twice as that of entity A or much more than that?
3. What other means can I use to find statistical information; do I have other tools in the cloud console of app engine, or can I do this programmatically ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size of a given index by running the code below.

```
from google.appengine.api import search

for index in search.get_indexes(fetch_schema=True):
    logging.info("index %s", index.storage_usage)
# pseudo code
amount_of_items_to_add = 100
x = 0
for x <= amount_of_items_to_add:
    search_api_insert_insert(data)
    x+=1
#rerun for loop to see how much the size increased
for index in search.get_indexes(fetch_schema=True):
    logging.info("index %s", index.storage_usage)
```

This code is obviously not a complete working example, but you should be able to build a simple method that takes some data inserts it into the search api and returns how much the used storage increased.

Answer (score 0):

I have run a number of tests for different number of entities and different number of indexed properties per entity and it seams thst the estimated growth of the index reported by the api is not exponential it is linear.
But the most interesting fact to know is that although the size reported is realtime almost, after deleting documents from the index, it may take 12, 24 even 36 hours to update.